# Prolog remove parenthesis when transforming list in polynomial

Tags: prolog

Basically when I try to transform a list into a polynomial or vice-versa, it always shows up with parenthesis (in case of the polynomials). Here is the code, the function not working is the poly2list, the other one are just to define what a monomial/polinomial is.

```
pvars([x,y,z]).
pvar(X):-pvars(V),member(X,V).

polinomial(X) :- monomial(X).
polinomial(P+M) :- monomial(M), polinomial(P).

monomial(X) :- pvar(X).
monomial(N) :- number(N).
monomial(X) :- power(X),!.
monomial(K*X) :- coefficient(K), power(X),!.

coefficient(N) :- number(N).

power(X) :- pvar(X),!.
power(X^Y) :- pvar(X), integer(Y), Y>1,!.

poly2list(X,[X]) :- monomial(X),!.
poly2list(X+P,[X|Y]) :- monomial(X), poly2list(P,Y).
```

For example, when i ask:
    `poly2list(X,[2*x^2,3,y]).`

The result is:
    `X = 2*x^2+(3+y)`

And I'm trying to get:
    `X = 2*x^2+3+y`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Make a *left recursive* expression.

Comment: Thank you, i managed to do it.